# I am trying to prove that a given tree is a binary search tree. I will input a binary tree and all i want is my function to return true

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to prove that a given tree is a binary search tree. I will input a binary tree and all i want is my function to return true.

```
 bool isbinary(bstnode* root){
    if(root==NULL) return;
    isbinary(root->left);
    isbinary(root->right);
    int data1=root->data;
    if((root->left->data<=data1&&root->right->data>data1) ||
       (root->left->data<=data1&&root->right==NULL) ||
       (root->right->data>data1&&root->left==NULL)) 
        return true;


// this doesnt work! i want to know the reason and a possible 
// solution in my line of thinking. TIA

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? (btw, we're not going to write the code for you)

Comment: is this approach correct to find if a tree is bst?

Comment: Take a look here - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/
Might help.

Comment: @sankar You shouldn't invalidate existing answers by editing your question this way. That's disrespecting the efforts of people that are actually trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return `true`/`false` then your function return type should be `bool` not `void`.

```
bool isbinary(bstnode* root){
.
.
.
return true/false;
}
```

EDIT:- as you corrected the typo, your recursion still has numerous flaws.If you don't have a tight grip on recursion, then you can do the simple inorder traversal of BST and store each node in a `temp array` simultaneously. As you know the inorder traversal gives the sorted nodes, you can easily check for it through that `temp array`.